# Code works in Netbeans, but not TextPad?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, nullpointerexception, textpad

Here is the code throwing the error. In TextPad, I get a NullPointerException when I try to  write the contents of the array to the text file. (It doesn't see anything in the array.) Note: it works perfectly in Netbeans. I only get this in Textpad. I have scoured Google and i have no idea why it is doing this.

```
    void enterContact(){
    // test contact
    contactName = nameField.getText();
    if (contactName == null || contactName.equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a name.");
        return;
    }

    //test age betweeen 0 and 120
    contactAge = ageField.getText();

    try{
        Integer.parseInt(contactAge);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid age.");
    }
    finally{
        if (Integer.parseInt(contactAge) <= 0 || Integer.parseInt(contactAge) >= 121){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid age.");
            return;
         }
    }

    // test email
    contactEmail = emailField.getText();
    if ( contactEmail == null || contactEmail.equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter an Email Address.");
        return;
    }

    //test cell number

    contactPhone = phoneField.getText();
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt(contactPhone);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter a valid Phone Number.");
        return;
    }

    String columns2[] =  {  contactName, contactAge, contactEmail, contactPhone  };

    //write data to file
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < columns2.length; i++){
            fw.write(columns2[i].toString() + ", ");
          }
        fw.write("\r\n");
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
```

Comment: Please post the **entire** error message including the compltete trace back.

Comment: You should post a stack trace so that we know which object is throwing the NullPointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get `NullPointerException` during writing in file, there is two possibilities:

1. You may not open the file. For example because of forgetting calling the constructor of `FileWriter`.
2. You don't have any permission to open the file and write into it.

If you got the exception only when you are run it using TextPad, I think the second problems occurred. You don't have permission.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Wk3Beets.enterContact(Wk3Beets.java:175)
        at Wk3Beets$1.actionPerformed(Wk3Beets.java:99)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:20
18)

Comment: thanks...this helped me to check where i was initializing the filewriter!

Answer (score 0):

Try To run your TextPad in Administrator Mode

Right Click on Textpad icon -> Run as administrator

& then RUN above program

i sure your program get executed properly.